# How can i get image name and image extension from image url

Tags: php

I have a image url with query strings. I just want to get image name and its extension in php.

```
https://static01.nyt.com/images/2018/08/28/us/28vote_print/28vote_xp-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale
```

Comment: did you try pathinfo() ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: Thanks @Inazo . It works amazing for me.

Comment: Hello @Inazo
 This is giving me "jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale" as extension but i just want "jpg"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) and [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$url = 'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2018/08/28/us/28vote_print/28vote_xp-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale';

// Getting the name
$name = pathinfo(parse_url($url)['path'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);

// Getting the extension
$ext = pathinfo(parse_url($url)['path'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Output:
var_dump($name);    // 28vote_xp-articleLarge
var_dump($ext);     // jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

use php `pathinfo()` function to get the details 
  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

```
$fileParts = pathinfo("https://static01.nyt.com/images/2018/08/28/us/28vote_print/28vote_xp-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale");
echo"<pre>";    
print_r($fileParts);
$extension=explode("?",$fileParts ['extension'])[0];
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [dirname] => https://static01.nyt.com/images/2018/08/28/us/28vote_print
    [basename] => 28vote_xp-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale
    [extension] => jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale
    [filename] => 28vote_xp-articleLarge
)
```

Comment: You need to remove the content in your url after the **?**

Comment: extension is not properly parsed.

Comment: No you added the output only. The extension is still not properly parsed.

Comment: @AymDev i have added this line bro `$extension=explode("?",$fileParts ['extension'])[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Refer:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

```
<?php

$parsedURL = parse_url('https://static01.nyt.com/images/2018/08/28/us/28vote_print/28vote_xp-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale');

$pathinfo = pathinfo($parsedURL['path']);

$filename = $pathinfo['filename'];
$extension = $pathinfo['extension'];

var_dump($filename, $extension);
```

Check the output: https://3v4l.org/vejBA